# kafka connect multiple topics in sink connector properties

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to read 2 kafka topics using Cassandra sink connector and insert into 2 Cassandra tables. How can I go about doing this?

This is my `connector.properties` file:

```
name=cassandra-sink-orders
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=topic1,topic2
connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO ks.table1 SELECT * FROM topic1;INSERT INTO ks.table2 SELECT * FROM topic2 
connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
connect.cassandra.port=9042
connect.cassandra.key.space=ks
connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
connect.cassandra.username=cassandra
connect.cassandra.password=cassandra
```

Am I doing everything right? Is this the best way of doing this or should I create two separate connectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to consume those two topics in one consumer that's fine and it's correct setup. The best way of doing this depends whether those messages should be consumed by one or two consumers. So it depends on your business logic.

Anyway, if you want to consume two topics via one consumer that should work find since consumer can subscribe to multiple topics. Did you try running this consumer? Is it working?

Answer (score 8):

There's one issue with your config. You need one task per topic-partition. So if your topics have one partition, you need `tasks.max` set to at least 2.

I don't see it documented in Connect's docs, which is a shame